# Encountering error while installing a NPM package

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt, node-pre-gyp

When I try to install bcrypt via NPM, I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path Z:\Authentication-Service\node_modules\bcrypt
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command bash -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! /mnt/z/Authentication-Service/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp: 11: exec: node: not found

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Xandrrrr\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-23T23_15_39_915Z-debug.log
```

What I've already tried:

- Reinstall node
- Validate the Path variable

My versions:

- Node `v16.7.0`
- NPM `7.20.3`

Comment: What command did you use to install bcrypt?

Comment: i used `node i bcrypt`

Comment: Isn't it `npm i bcrypt`?

Comment: I'm kinda stupid, I made a Typo. Yes, i used `npm i bcrypt` (Typo here in the comments, not in the terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Node `v16.7.0` is not the `LTS` version.

May be it has deprecated some features that `bcrypt` requires (but I'm not sure)!

Try downgrading Node to the current `LTS` version `v14.17.6`